# How can I loop a song with Windows Media Player in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net-2010, axwindowsmediaplayer

Previously I was playing it like

```
 My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.island, AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

But for different reasons(such as: lack of setting possibilities), thats not good enough, so I changed to Windows media player, but I have not a clue, how to make the sound loop in the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("Loop", True)
```

Comment: That repeats all songs though, and not just a single song.